# Or he might as well have

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've read a text saying

> But Sutherland could have made the weeklong climb blindfolded. He’d done it before, or may as well have.

What is the meaning of "or may as well have" in this context? If he definitely had done it before, why add this phrase? Is this some widely used collocation?

Comment: Hi Longist. Welcome to E.L.L.! He hasn't really done it blindfolded, but perhaps he did it in thick fog. On that occasion perhaps the fog was so thick he may as well have been blindfolded. Or perhaps last time he only climbed at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll paraphrase:

**Even though Sutherland didn't make the weeklong climb blindfolded, his expertise was identical to have actually done so.** (I think this best paraphrases your example.)

Or:

**Even though Sutherland didn't make the weeklong climb blindfolded, visibility was so poor that it was as if he had actually done so.** (This is also common.)

In short, it means that regardless of what happened in reality, the other action ("may as well have") could have happened instead with the identical result.